# Update the value of an NSSlider in realtime

Tags: swift, macos, swift3, nsslider

In my swift 3 app, I have an NSSlider that I created like this:

```
self.myAwesomeSlider = NSSlider(frame:CGRect(x: 10, y: 100, width: 20, height: 300))
self.myAwesomeSlider?.cell = NSSlider()
self.myAwesomeSlider?.maxValue = 127
self.myAwesomeSlider?.target = self
self.myAwesomeSlider?.isContinuous = true
self.view?.addSubview(self.myAwesomeSlider!)
```

What I want to do now, is (from another function) update the value of this slider in realtime.

I tried to do it very basic like this:

```
self.myAwesomeSlider?.integerValue = Int(value)
```

but it doesnt update the dot. What I wish to get is new value gets calculated and dot on slider does move according to the value.

Is this possible?

thank you

---

Edit

```
self.myAwesomeSlider?.integerValue = Int(value)
```

Apparently, this does work, however, I have to click on another application before I see actual change.

Comment: [change NSSlider Value programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9867343/change-nsslider-value-programmatically?rq=1) Here they do it programmatically as you request :)

Comment: @Kimdv yes they do, and it's the normal way of setting the value, however, i'd like for mine to update in realtime, so I need to be able to set the value after the fact, which isn't exactly working for me when doing it like that.

Comment: UI elements are only updated when program control returns to the main event loop (and must be updated on the main thread).

Comment: @MartinR So it's not a possivbility?

Comment: @WesleyLi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015767/nsslider-animation?rq=1 here is how they animate it, by changing the value.

Comment: @Kimdv Would you know how to implement this in Swift? Haha

Answer (score -1):

```
myAwesomeSlider.addTarget(self, action: "sliderValueChanged:", 
                      forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

func sliderValueChanged() {    
    var slider = sender as! UISlider
    label.text = "\(slider.value)"
}
```

Comment: Please, add explanation on **why** this code will answer the issue.

Comment: Small issue, this is code for IOS, can't use stuff like that for mac development